# How to cancel a call to api on clicking a button in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

i make a request to server to load data related to item  on clicking item button. However, on clicking cancel button it should abort the request to load data. How can i do it. Below is the code,

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(this.props.item) {
        this.load_item_data();
    }
}

load_item_data = () => {
    const props = this.props;
    this.file_download_status = {};
    if (this.on_item_changed) {
        this.on_item_changed();
    }
    const item_changed = new Promise((resolve) => { this.on_item_changed = 
    resolve; });
    const abort_loading = Promise.race([item_changed, this.unmount]);

    item
        .load(props.item.id, gl, this.update_download_progress, 
    abort_loading).then((result) => {
            this.files = result.files;
            this.setState({
                item_download_done: true,
            });
            client.add_item_view(props.item.id, abort_loading);
        });
```

How can i abort the above request on clicking a cancel button? Thanks.

Comment: You can cancel requests with axios. And you should be using some kind of state management framework like redux (and I recommend the redux-saga middleware) to handle problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it's in the documentation of Axios

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

axios.get('/user/12345', {
  cancelToken: source.token
}).catch(function (thrown) {
  if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
    console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
  } else {
    // handle error
  }
});

axios.post('/user/12345', {
  name: 'new name'
}, {
  cancelToken: source.token
})

// cancel the request (the message parameter is optional)
source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
```

Check the link:-
https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

Comment: I believe you should reject() the promise after source.cancel()